# How do I create a list of characters, with the non-whitespace chars nested in the list?

Tags: string, list, common-lisp

I am trying to get a list of characters to be stored in their own list, nested in another list, that is delimited by Space chars.

The expected output would be as follows: `((\#w \#o \#r \#d) \#Space (\#w \#o \#r \#d))`

Here is the function that I wrote for it:

```lisp
(defun string->list (str)
  "Take a string, split it into chars and add it into a list."
  (let ((list-string '()))
    (loop for x from 0 to (- (length str) 1)
          do (push (char str x) list-string))
    (nreverse list-string)))
```

Which outputs `(\#w \#o \#r \#d \#Space \#w \#o \#r \#d)`

I tried to use loops to try and get the nesting to happen, but the output ultimately was the same. I tried looking elsewhere, but couldn't find a satisfactory answer.

Here is the revised function for reference:

```lisp
(defun string->list (str)
  (let ((list-string '()))
    (loop for letter from 0 to (- (length str) 1)
          if (equal (char str letter)  #\Space)
          do (push (char str letter) list-string)
          else 
          do (push (char str letter) list-string))
    (nreverse list-string)))
```

I would appreciate some pointers of how to approach this problem. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to keep space characters in the list of lists of word characters? It seems like the spaces would be implicit in a list of characters lists such as `((\#w \#o \#r \#d) (\#w \#o \#r \#d))`. What should happen with, e.g., `"words  separated    by    multiple       spaces"`?

Answer (score 1):

I would use the `split` function from [CL-PPCRE](http://edicl.github.io/cl-ppcre/) but you can easily reimplement a similar split function (without regexes) yourself.

```
(rest
  (mapcan (lambda (w) (list #\space (coerce w 'list)))
          (ppcre:split #\space "word word")))
```

The call to `ppcre:split` transforms:

```
 "word word"
```

into

```
 ("word" "word")
```

Then, for each string W in the list, the lambda computes the following list, where L is a list of characters:

```
 (#\space L)
```

For example:

```
> ((lambda (w) (list #\space (coerce w 'list))) "example")
(#\  (#\e #\x #\a #\m #\p #\l #\e))
```

By the way, the `#\space` character is outputted as `#\`  in the output.

This anonymous function is called for every word resulting from the split. With the given input example, that would be twice the same list:

```
((#\  (#\w #\o #\r #\d)) 
((#\  (#\w #\o #\r #\d))
```

Additionally, `mapcan` takes all these intermediary lists and chain them together to form a single list:

```
(#\  (#\w #\o #\r #\d) #\  (#\w #\o #\r #\d))
```

If there is at least one element, there is necessarily a superfluous `#\space` in front of the list, so it discards it with `rest` (which behaves appropriately too if the list is empty). Finally, the result is:

```
((#\w #\o #\r #\d) #\  (#\w #\o #\r #\d))
```

Note that if you have multiple spaces, the output is:

```
((#\w #\o #\r #\d) #\  NIL #\  NIL #\  NIL #\  NIL #\  (#\w #\o #\r #\d))
```

To me it satisfies your specification but in case you intended to split over continuous sequences of whitespaces you would need to change the regular expression that performs the split, for example:

```
(ppcre:split "\\s+" ...)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a recursive approach :

```
(defun constituent (c)
  "predicate that returns T for all graphics characters except the
whitespace."
  (and (graphic-char-p c)
       (char/= c #\ )))

(defun string->list (str &optional (pred #'constituent) (start 0))
  "Take a string, split it into chars and add it into a list."
  (let ((pos-start (position-if pred str :start start)))
    (when pos-start
      (let ((pos-end (position-if-not pred str :start pos-start)))
        (if pos-end
            (cons (coerce (subseq str pos-start pos-end) 'list)
                  (cons #\Space (string->list str pred pos-end)))
            (list (coerce (subseq str pos-start) 'list)))))))

CL-USER> (string->list "word word")
((#\w #\o #\r #\d) #\  (#\w #\o #\r #\d))
```

I don't know why you'd want to keep a #\Space character between the two lists...

Comment: you could rearrange the end to factorize a little bit: `(cons (coerce (subseq str pos-start pos-end) 'list) (and pos-end (cons #\space (string->list str pred pos-end))))`, by the way isn't it `(1+ pos-end)` in the recursive call?

Comment: The use of position-if to find the indice of the next char to extract (pos-start) can :start on the pos-end of last call. So you don't need to (1+ pos-end).

Answer (score 0):

I would use an extra list for the current word which gets dumped on list-string when the word delimiter is reached:

```
(defun string->list (str)
  (let (list-string word-string)
    (loop for letter across str
          if (equal letter  #\Space)
          do (progn (push (nreverse word-string) list-string)
                            (setq word-string nil)
                              (push letter list-string) )
          else 
          do (push letter word-string))
    (push (nreverse word-string) list-string) 
    (nreverse list-string)))

(string->list "word1 word2")
  ((#\w #\o #\r #\d #\1) #\Space (#\w #\o #\r #\d #\2))
```